# Access Form Validation from Outside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am beginner in angular.I have form which has validation that enable the **save** button only on **validation pass**

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" ng-disabled="!frmRegister.$valid" />
```

I have **directive** which will take care of form submission globally.

```
app.directive('mysavebtn',function(){
            return {                
                restrict : "E",
                scope :{
                },
                controller : function($scope){

                },
                link : function(scope,elem,attr){

                },
                template : '<div style="clear:both;" >'
                 +'<input type="submit" ng-disabled="!frmRegister.$valid" value="Directive Save"  />'
           +'</div>'
            }
        });
```

But Directive save button always disabled even when form is valid!!!.**Note:**      I keep save button inside form to know the validation

Please check [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XamC9MYsITaSGyqRNvT6?p=preview) in working example

How do i get access Form validation from **mysavebtn** directive ? Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an isolated scope inside your  directive you can pass the state of the form validity inside that scope using '=' notation (2-way binding). For that purpose you need to modify the HTML of your directive a bit:

```
<mysavebtn form-valid="frmRegister.$valid"></mysavebtn>
```

and also JS:

```
app.directive('mysavebtn', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      formValid: "="
    },
    controller: function($scope) {

    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

    },
    template: '<div style="clear:both;" >' + '<input type="submit" ng-disabled="!formValid" value="Directive Save"  />' + '</div>'
  }
});
```

Now the form validity state is available inside the directive's template through
the formValid variable.
See the working [PLNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/reulAxGY5J6dWEZysvnD?p=preview).
For more information read Angular [directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/directive) guide.

Answer (score 1):

One of the recommended ways of inter-directive communication and best practice is to **use `require` to get access to other directive controller** (`form` directive in this case).

I modified your plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rGxmu7M33Ftb52MobzdK?p=preview

```
app.directive('mysavebtn', function () {
  return {              
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^form',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, formCtrl) {
      scope.formCtrl = formCtrl;
    },
    template: '<div style="clear:both;">' +
      '<input type="submit" ng-disabled="!formCtrl.$valid" value="Directive Save"  />' +
    '</div>'
  }
});
```

**Place your `mysavebtn` into `form`** so it has access to it. You now have access to the whole `form` API and have much more possibilities.

BTW: Creating binding for this is unnecessary (as in the now accepted other answer).